# transform each element of tuple; get that tuple

Tags: d

I have a tuple in D. I want to apply an element-wise operation on that tuple, and get that transformed tuple for passing into another function that accepts variadic template arguments. The execution path of the transform is defined at compile time, but the actual value is not.

The purpose of this is similar to the template mechanism used in C++'s `bind` construct, for determining where to use placeholders/passed arguments and where to use stored arguments at compile time.

How do I accomplish this?

<sub>this is the first time in D I've ever missed a feature in C++11's template system: the pack/unpack operator - please make me not feel bad :-(</sub>

EDIT: Ended up using `mixin`s, because apparently any generic programming solution you want can be solved by using them. May answer with them if no one comes up with anything more elegant than taking D's ridiculously powerful jackhammer-of-a-generic-programming-tool to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element of a tuple can be anything that a template alias parameter can be. However, run-time expressions cannot be alias parameters - they are evaluated at compile time. Thus, it is not possible to transform a tuple using a transformation that runs at compile-time (barring workarounds such as where the transformation defines a @property function that returns the result).

If the expression and transformation *can* be evaluated at compile-time, see [staticMap](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_typetuple.html#.staticMap) from std.typetuple.

Comment: Ah, so I basically had to use mixins the way that I did to construct the expressions and let them run their course at runtime. I'ma +1, but it technically didn't answer my question. >_<

Comment: I'm having some difficulty visualizing your requirements. Could you elaborate on what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I already got it. What I was trying to do was replicate how Boost bind works (because for whatever reason, there doesn't appear to be anything in std.functional that does quite the same thing w/ placeholders and somesuch). So I got to storing all of the bind arguments (including placeholders), but got stuck at trying to choose the stored bind argument or the passed argument for any one argument index. So instead I just composed the entire function call as a string and mixed it in.

Comment: D1 had std.bind, but it was deprecated in favor of D2 closures. Just return the address of a nested function; the nested function will have access to its parent function's local variables and parameters, even after the parent function exited. (Note that this involves a heap allocation and relies on the garbage collector to clean it up.)

Comment: I really wanted to avoid relying on the GC for something that seemed so trivial. Admittedly, I'm being idealistic, but I feel like the GC is some sort of slippery slope where if I start using it I won't be able to stop and suddenly I'll be generating an F-ton more garbage than I need to. This was one of those cases where I was pretty sure that I didn't need to generate garbage (because Boost Bind did without it). I mean, I love the way D handles delegates with the frame pointer and all, but I don't want to outright rely on it. Throwing my hands in the air like that just feels so wrong.

Comment: It would help if you described the general problem you were trying to solve. You've said you tried to "replicate how Boost bind works"; what were you trying to achieve by doing that?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question right, then this is possible but it's a highly experimental (undocumented and not guaranteed to always work) feature:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.traits;
import std.typetuple;

ReturnType!Call Delay(alias Call, alias arg)() { return Call(arg); }

template Map(alias Call, args...)
{
    static if (args.length > 1)
        alias Map = TypeTuple!(Delay!(Call, args[0]),Map!(Call, args[1..$]));
    else
        alias Map = Delay!(Call, args[0]);
}

int square(int arg)
{
    return arg * arg;
}

void print(int res1, int res2)
{
    writefln("%s %s", res1, res2);  // writes '25 100'
}

void test(Args...)(Args args)
{
    print(Map!(square, args));
}

void main()
{
    int x = 5;
    int y = 10;
    test(x, y);
}
```

Originally asked here: [Mapping variadic template arguments in D](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12888263/mapping-variadic-template-arguments-in-d/12926873)